# Doctrine ORM: Best method of using a ticket server to generate primary ids?

Tags: php, database, doctrine, sharding, doctrine-1.2

I am in the process of creating a centralized ticket server for handing out unique 32bit INT ids.  I have a function that can be called within my application that accepts a parameter for the entity/ table, e.g. getPrimaryKey('user').  I got the idea from Flickr via this blog post:

http://code.flickr.com/blog/2010/02/08/ticket-servers-distributed-unique-primary-keys-on-the-cheap/

We will eventually be sharding our data amongst multiple MySQL databases and I would like to get this code up and running as a proof of concept.

My question is what is the best method for using this functionality within Doctrine?  Obviously, using the above ticket server, I will need to specify that none of my Doctrine models contain an auto- incrementing primary key.

Is there a Doctrine_Model method I can extend that will retrieve the primary key using my getPrimaryKey method prior to inserting a new record into the database?  If not, should I be approaching this problem from another place within my application?

Ideally, I would like the ids to be generated using the above method when using Doctrine relations such as:

```
$user = new User():  
$user->name = 'Bob';  
$user->Phonenumbers[]->number = '555-5555';  
$user->save();
```

Also, the other side of this scenario is in selecting data from a particular shard.  My current thought is to maintain a master list of key ranges contained on each shard like this (ignore the small number of rows per shard):

Shard A user_id 1-1000
Shard B user_id 1001-2000
Shard C user_id 2001-3000

I can then call something like getShard($table_name, $primary_key) to get the shard and possibly switch my Doctrine connection to that particular shard.  Related data for a particular user/entity will most likely reside on the same shard so I am not too worried relations spanning multiple shards. Though, it may be a possibility, so any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated as well.